# Decide large process and notify users

Tags: asp.net-core

I have some processing to do at server side.

When user selects large amount of data for processing (let's say, they are insert, update, delete in database and file read/write stuffs), it takes so much time.

I am using c# with .net core mvc web application.

In this case, is it possible to decide when process takes more than some decided time, run it into background (or say transfer process to another tool if possible) and notify user that it will take some time and u will be notified once done (that notification need not be real time. We can mail)

So is there any mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and create a job for processing the data, you can try [**hangfire**](https://www.hangfire.io/), that allows you to create background jobs inside your aspnet core application.

Comment: Is there a way to create a job only if process took time more than specified? any mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to make what you want. On the other hand you can use parallel foreach to process more data faster.

Ex:

```
Parallel.ForEach([list of entities],
                 new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },
                 [entity] =>
                 {
                   //YOURCODE PROCESSING THE ENTITY (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE)
                 }
);
```

The property MaxDegreeOfParallelism defines how many threads you're going to use in maximum. I suggest you to start with 2 and increase one by one to see what's the best fit for you.

Parallel foreach is going to use more threads to process your data.

If parallel foreach does not solve your problem, you can use an strategy that consists in receiving your users data, assumes that this processing is going to take a long time, stores this data as is on your database or any other kind of storage, give your user a answer back with a transaction id and a text explaining that it's going to take a long time and the response is going to be sent by e-mail. By doing it you will need to build another service to process these transaction and e-mail the users with anything you think is necessary.

Another possibility is, instead of notifying the user through e-mail, you can create a method to check the processing status based on a transaction id and do a pooling strategy so the user won't even notice that the processing is being done in background.

Hope you succeed

Best Regards